# decode_utf8 consumes time in execution

Tags: performance, perl, profiling, execution-time

The following is the code snippet that I have been working on to improve its speed.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Encode;

open(IN,"<utf8",$ARGV[0]) or die "Cannot open $ARGV[0]:$!\n"; ##treat it as a huge data of 35,000 lines in devnagari script.
my @in = <IN>;
close(IN);

my $key = "अच्छा";  #key to be matched contains devanagari script as a string 

foreach my $in(@in) {
    chomp($in);
    $key = decode_utf8($key);
        $in = decode_utf8($in);
    if($key eq $in) {
        print "$key: matched\n";
    }
    else {
        print "Not matched\n";
    }
}
```

I am  trying to match the lines in the file with key.
By profiling my code following are the results I get.

[image]

The results are such that `decode_utf8` consumes 34% of time.
Since my data is in utf8 I used `decode_utf8`.

What can I do to improve the speed here. Any other workaround for replacing `decode_utf8` in the code to match the unicode data.

Comment: If you're using PerlIO layers on the filehandle, the decoding is done for you. (Although `utf8` doesn't mean anything. You probably meant `:utf8` even though you _actually_ want `:encoding(utf8)`.) If you have Unicode characters in your source code, you need to `use utf8;`. You shouldn't read the entire file into memory if you don't have to, and you shouldn't have an array and a scalar with the same name, because it's confusing.

Comment: And, despite all of the obvious goofiness with your code, the total run time is still less than a second. Why does it need to be faster than that?

Comment: without going into detail about UTF-8 and decoding/encoding issues... you can reduce the time spend on decode_utf8 by half of the time: you are calling that function every iteration on $key, in general (with any function), you can move that outside the loop and use my $key_decoded = decode_utf8($key). then inside the loop use $key_decoded to compare with your $in.

Comment: @MattJacob the code execution time posted here is just a working example in real it takes almost around 20 seconds in real time(huge database). And I have a main file that is opening the file in utf8 and in another subroutine decode_utf8 is called. The issue here is I dont want to be editing the main file from where the file is being opened

Comment: @vanHoesel Yes its in the loop. I just prepared a snippet to make the users here understand the time taken for it to execute. I wanted to know is there anything I can do to avoid decode_utf8

Answer (score 1):

> *The results are such that decode_utf8 consumes 34% of time.*

Well yeah, that's basically all your program does.

More importantly, your code is buggy. You're decoding previously decoded strings!

- You decode the contents of the file when you read them (via `:utf8`), and then you decode the already-decoded content in the loop.
- You decode the contents of `$key` every pass through the loop so that by the fourth pass, you are using `decode_utf8(decode_utf8(decode_utf8(decode_utf8($key))))`.

Fix:

```
use utf8;                             # Source code encoded using UTF-8.    
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';  # Term provides and expects UTF-8. Default for files.

use strict;
use warnings;

my $key = "अच्छा";

my $found = 0;
while (my $line = <>) {
    chomp($line);
    if ($line eq $key) {
        $found = 1;
        last;
    }
}

if ($found) {
    print "Match found\n";
else {
    print "No match\n";
}
```

This fixes other issues too:

- Encodes outputs (using `use open ':std'`).
- Doesn't needlessly use global variables. (Use `open my $IN` instead of `open IN`.)
- Doesn't needlessly load the entire file into memory.
- Doesn't needlessly read the entire file.
- Doesn't print `Not matched` 34,999 times when the key is found.
- Avoids `:utf8` in favour of `:encoding(UTF-8)`.
- Doesn't reinvent `<>`.
- Doesn't hide a `die` in the middle of a line. (Put a line break before `or die`.)
- Doesn't use "cannot". (Use "can't"!)

Comment: You've changed the intent of the original code. Instead of looking for `$key` in every line, you're only matching it once across the entire file.

Comment: @Matt Jacob, You have it backwards. The original code was buggy, and I produced the code that produces the intended result. There's no reason to believe the OP wanted to print the number of matches. And even if they did, the `if` should still be moved outside of the loop. (Just replace `$found=1;last;` with `++$found;`.) And hey, if the check really should be in the loop, the OP already knows how to do that, so nothing was lost.

Comment: @ikegami I wanted to reproduce a minimal and verifiable working example to reproduce the issue.So the code looks buggy. In reality all these happens in multiple subroutines. I had intentionally placed utf8 in source code but actually that variable is also assigned from a file. And also read my comments that I clarified with the question to other users.

Comment: I don't see your point. What is your comment trying to say? Why do you think it matter if your bugs actually span subroutines? Have you fixed them as I showed you yet? Your other comments are also irrelevant, so I'm not sure why you bring those up either. Except maybe the fact that some inputs come from the db. Cause there again, it's far cleaner to just ask the db driver to decode for you.

Comment: I mean in order to make a minimal example these bugs have encounterted. I fixed the loading of entire file into memory. But I am still stuck with utf8. I am trying to find where am I doing wrong while dealing with utf8 in the subroutines that are being used. @ikegami

Comment: Did you remove the calls to decode_utf8 and the IO layer on the open statement, keeping only the first two lines of the code I posted? Read the accompanying comments!!!

Comment: I have multiple files that are being read using Getopt::Long; Can I read them without the IO layer?

Comment: Getopt::Long doesn't read any files. /// I think you'll need `use open ':encoding(UTF-8)';` (no `:std`) in the other source files that use `open` (or use `:encoding(UTF-8)` in the `open` function call, or decode manually).